# Get logged in user attributes as a collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to get the logged in users attributes, I do this via:

```
Auth::user()->attributesToArray();
```

But I would ideally like this as a collection - how can I do this?

```
collect(Auth::user()->attributesToArray());
```

The above just wraps the returned array in a collection.

Comment: Auth::user() return collections.Why are you using tattributesToArray()?

Comment: Why (specifically) do you want it to be a collection. Also, why is it that the attributes to collection example that you've provided doesn't work for you i.e. in what way would you like it to be different?

Comment: What's wrong with your own example? Ins't that exactly what a collection is? a wrapper around an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply create a custom attribute:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function getAttributesToCollectionAttribute()
    {
        return collect($this->attributesToArray);
    }
}

// $user->attributesToCollection or $user->attributes_to_collection.
```